# What is the difference between non-programmable random oracle model and standard model？

Tags: random-oracle-model

I know Common ground of them is that in both model the simulator cannot choose the reply for the query, and the difference between them is that in NPROM the simulator can still see the query/answer list, while in standard model it cannot. Anything else about them?